# Getting Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I've been wracking my brains out over the past few days trying to figure this one out:

I'm currently making a level based game using Flashpunk. The way I handle levels is by simply passing a OGMO editor file (it's basically just a xml file with a different extension) in arrays like so:

```
public static var worldOneList:Array = new Array(LEVEL_WORLD_1_1, LEVEL_WORLD_1_2,etc..);
public static var worldTwoList:Array = new Array(LEVEL_WORLD_1_1, LEVEL_WORLD_1_2,etc..);

public static var worldLists:Array = new Array(worldOneList,worldTwoList,etc...);
```

and then calling it in the form of a class that handles map creation and level logic:

```
    public static function toLevel(worldID:int, levelID:int):void
    {
        FP.world = new LevelBase(worldLists[worldID][levelID]);
    }
```

I can access levels just fine through the level select screen, however upon completing a level and choosing to advance to the next one, I get thrown:

```
Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
```

With the top of the stack pointing to (in FP):

```
        public static function getXML(file:Class):XML
    {
        var bytes:ByteArray = new file;
        return XML(bytes.readUTFBytes(bytes.length));
    }
```

The strange thing is that the first two levels will go just fine, then upon the third and any after that, it'll throw up the error.

This is the code I use to change levels:

```
if (GlobalVar.currentLevel[1] != GlobalVar.maxLevelsInSet)
{
            LevelLists.toLevel(GlobalVar.currentLevel[0], GlobalVar.currentLevel[1] + 1);
}
```

And the code to read the ogmo files (in LevelBase.as):

```
public function LevelBase(levelFile:Class)
{

        levelData = FP.getXML(levelFile); //Parse the .oel file and give data to levelData
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something pretty simple wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Cheers :)

Comment: So I figured out what was wrong: turns out my method for advancing through the levels (GlobalVar.currentLevel[1] + 1) is not adding 1 to the ID, but for some reason adding an extra digit to the value. This means the 3rd level is returning "11" as the ID and not 2, and since there's only 10 levels in a world, there's obviously no XML file to parse. Is this normal behavior, or a weird AS3 bug?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot see what GlobalVar is, or currentLevel, but from your comment that is adding a digit on the end, and not adding - it looks like that GlobalVar.currentLevel[1] is a string. So, in order to add values, cast to int or Number first, than do the operation.